# Visual Studio Git

Tags: visual-studio, github

I use my Surface Pro 7 as my development machine.

Since the SSD only 256GB and the storage almost full.
So I plug a micro SD Card as `D:` and put the project on `D:` drive.

I think there is problem if I put my project to removable storage that Visual Studio cannot push the project changes to Github.
Is it the restriction of Git that the project cannot saved to removable storage?

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction: as long as VSCode uses your project (stored in your case in a removable storage drive), Git itself will run the `git push` (through VSCode) from that local folder.

The push does not depend on the local folder nature, just on the presence of Git data (in the `.git` repository folder).

Comment: Hi,  I try the "git pull" cli command in PowerShell the changes can update to GitHub.  However when I try the action in Visual Studio (not VSCode), I can "Commit" the changes but the "Push" button is grey out on the Git Tab.

Comment: @user2114189 What `git remote -v` returns?

Comment: origin  https://github.com/<username>/<project>.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<username>/<project>.git (push)

Comment: I also try:  manual push the changes to GitHub via Cli "gut push".  Restart Visual Studio.  It seem fixed the push button grey out problem.  The button is enabled again and the changes can push to GitHub inside Visual Studio.

Comment: @user2114189 Great, well done!